# Could not run build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app on <iphonedevice>

Tags: flutter, ios17

Error Messange:

```
Could not run build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app on <iphonedevice>.
Try launching Xcode and selecting "Product > Run" to fix the problem:
  open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
```

It was working fine originally in real machine, but it broke after I updated it to ios17 and xcode15.

And I try to run it in Xcode and it works, but it doesn’t work in Android studio and VSCode.

Flutter doctor -v:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.12, on macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64, locale
    zh-Hant-TW)
    • Flutter version 3.7.12 on channel stable at
      /Users/davis_ho/fvm/versions/3.7.12
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 4d9e56e694 (6 months ago), 2023-04-17 21:47:46 -0400
    • Engine revision 1a65d409c7
    • Dart version 2.19.6
    • DevTools version 2.20.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/davis_ho/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15A240d
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.82.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.72.0
```

Already tried:

1. Reinstalling flutter.
2. Unparing & paring the iPhone in Xcode.
3. Uninstalling the app.
4. VPN & Device Management, to accept or trust.

Comment: are you trying to run the app on your real device or simulator?

Comment: Initially, I was running it on a real device, but it didn’t work after the update.

Comment: This is the issue with macos 14, xcode 15 and ios version 16+. I am also facing same issue. It isn't futter specific problem.

Comment: how to fix this? Any workaround?

Comment: I upgraded Flutter to 3.13.6 and it works!

Comment: write your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solve

I upgraded Flutter to 3.13.6 and it works!

#### Flutter 3.13.5 Change

```
3.13.5 (September 20, 2023)
flutter/134825 - Fixes an issue where apps built in profile mode would not install or run on physical iOS 17 devices.
flutter/45598 - Fix permissions on macos artifacts making mac framework readable and executable by all
```

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/releases/tag/3.13.5

Answer (score 0):

1- Upgrade to Flutter 3.13.9 • channel stable
2- cd iOS in terminal android studio
3- flutter clean
4- flutter pub get
5- pod install
6- run from android studio
7- make allowed Xcode and android studio go to Privacy & Security > Automation
8- done